# Word for: I can feel music inside me

Tags: music

I’ve heard a lot of musicians and music lovers say: ‘I can feel the music inside of me.’ Is there a word for that?

Comment: "vibe" is the best I can think of

Answer (score 1):

*This might be taking the question a bit too literally, but I thought I'd post the answer anyway because it's an interesting word.*

There's a neurological phenomenon called **Synesthesia** that can cause people to literally feel music (or other sounds). From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synesthesia):

> Synesthesia (also spelled synæsthesia or synaesthesia; from the
>   Ancient Greek σύν syn, "together", and αἴσθησις aisthēsis,
>   "sensation") is a neurological phenomenon in which stimulation of one
>   sensory or cognitive pathway leads to automatic, involuntary
>   experiences in a second sensory or cognitive pathway.

[Specifically for sounds causing physical sensations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synesthesia#Auditory-tactile_synesthesia):

> In auditory-tactile synesthesia, certain sounds can induce sensations
>   in parts of the body. For example, someone with auditory-tactile
>   synesthesia may experience that hearing a specific word feels like
>   touch in one specific part of the body or may experience that certain
>   sounds can create a sensation in the skin without being touched [...]

Answer (score 0):

Probably not.  It's analogous to seeing images in "your mind's eye,"  and I don't think there's a single word for that either.